# Irregular Grid and Hamiltonian paths

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a question. Is there an efficient way to get the Hamiltonian paths between two nodes in a grid graph, leaving some predefined nodes out?

eg. (4*3 grid)

```
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 2 3
```

finding a Hamiltonian paths in this grid b/w vertices 1 and 2, but not covering 3? It seems bipartite graphs are a way, but what according to you must be the most efficient way. The problem itself is NP complete.

Comment: What is your graph representation? Are these rows adjacency lists?

Comment: Oh, actually, I *think* I got it. You have nodes that are laid out on a grid, and you've marked three vertices on that grid that are of interest. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, I have to find the hamiltonian path between vertex numbered 1(starting point) and vertex numbered 2(end point). but I should not include vertex number 3 in my path.

Comment: What is the connectivity on this graph? Just left-right-up-down? Or diagonals also? Are all edge-weights equal?

Comment: An example would be

1--0--0--0
         |
0--0--0--0
|
0--0--2  3

this example is a sort of zig zag connectivity

Comment: No i cannot connect diagonally, only neighbours

Comment: and yeah all edge weights are equal. I cannot connect diagonals, meaning i can connect only those vertices with unit distance between them ( a normal grid graph). That is why I was thinking of converting it to a bipartite one, wanted to make sure it would help

Comment: @ArunShyam  `1 0 0 0 2` will be shorter going down till end then right. SO you want to find longest path or any path?

Comment: no i have to cover all the zeros. Starting with 1 and ending at 2, but not cover 3

Comment: _"The problem itself is NP complete."_ The general Hamiltonian path problem is NP-complete. But your set of graphs is seems to be highly constrained. It's not clear _a priori_ that this particular problem is NP-complete. (If it is, say goodbye to an efficient general algorithm.)

Comment: according to [this paper](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf) the problem as  stated is indeed np-complete (cf. Sect.2, Cor.2 [p.681]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the nodes you dont need to include and run the brute force algorithm to find Hamiltonian path. This will take O((n-h)!+n), which is NP, where h is the number of nodes deleted, but that is the best you can do. Also to find Hamiltonian path, there is a dynamic approach but that too is exponential( O(2^n*n^2))

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to leave those predefined nodes out: just consider them *visited* and you can still work your graph as a rectangular grid graph. I'd recommend a bitset or bitvector representation for the grid if efficiency is important.

When the grid is this small, 4x3, a brute force approach is the fastest. Dynamic programming makes it actually slower unless you have a bigger graph (6x7+). You can also use heuristics to prune your search tree, but again, the graph has to be bigger before it helps.